# how can i access a value that's being updated by a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

here's the value of ACCOUNT_NUMBER that has been generated by a sequence and inserted in ACCOUNTS table by ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG trigger that i need to insert it into the TRANSACTION TABLE by the trigger  ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON ACCOUNTS
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER is not null)
DECLARE
  V_ACC_NO ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNT_NO_SEQ.nextvaL INTO V_ACC_NO FROM DUAL;
  :NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER := V_ACC_NO;

END ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1 AFTER
  INSERT ON ACCOUNTS FOR EACH ROW DECLARE CURSOR ACCOUNTS_CUR IS
  SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM ACCOUNTS;
  DECLARE 
  TEMP_1 NUMBER(5,0);
  BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM INSERTED INTO TEMP_1
    OPEN ACCOUNTS_CUR;
    INSERT
    INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES
      (
         SYSDATE,
      - :NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        'NEW ACCOUNT',
        0
      );
    CLOSE ACCOUNTS_CUR;
  END ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1;
```

Comment: Did you try add a column which updated or inserted by trigger something like column_trigger? When trigger works, update or insert this column = 1 or true.

Comment: The thing is that i need to insert a new record that contains the value of the column updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
   ACCOUNT_NUMBER number,
   ACCOUNT_NAME varchar2(20)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE ACCOUNT_NO_SEQ;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON ACCOUNTS
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER is not null)
BEGIN
  :NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER :=ACCOUNT_NO_SEQ.nextvaL;
END ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG;
/
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
  TR_DATE  date,
  TR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER number,
  TR_TYPE varchar2(20),
  TR_somenumber int
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1 AFTER
  INSERT ON ACCOUNTS FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS( TR_DATE, TR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, TR_TYPE, TR_somenumber )
    VALUES
      (
         SYSDATE,
        :NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        'NEW ACCOUNT',
        0
      );
  END ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1;
  /
```

---

```
INSERT INTO accounts( ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NAME ) VALUES (1111,'My Name' );

select * from  accounts;
ACCOUNT_NUMBER ACCOUNT_NAME        
-------------- --------------------
             2 My Name  

select * from transactions;
TR_DATE    TR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER TR_TYPE              TR_SOMENUMBER
---------- ----------------- -------------------- -------------
2017/07/11                 2 NEW ACCOUNT                      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CURVAL to get the most recent value returned by NEXTVAL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1 AFTER
  INSERT ON ACCOUNTS FOR EACH ROW DECLARE CURSOR ACCOUNTS_CUR IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT
    INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES
      (
         SYSDATE,
       - ACCOUNT_NO_SEQ.curval,
        'NEW ACCOUNT',
        0
      );
    CLOSE ACCOUNTS_CUR;
  END ACCOUNTS_TRANSCATION_TRIG_1;
```

However in this case there is no need, as it has been used to set the ACOUNT_NUMBER:

```
    INSERT
    INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES
      (
         SYSDATE,
       - :NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        'NEW ACCOUNT',
        0
      );
```

BTW unless you are on an old version of Oracle this should work for first trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON ACCOUNTS
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER is not null)
BEGIN
  :NEW.ACCOUNT_NUMBER := ACCOUNT_NO_SEQ.nextvaL;
END ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TRIG;
```

(I suspect the WHEN clause is wrong - should be when **is** null?)

Comment: Shouldn't need to access the sequence currval in this case, since the before trigger has put the sequence value into the account_number column.